# How to handle file upload with fields along with custom file validation handling?

Tags: express, file-upload, mern, multer

I am trying to upload a file (avtar) with few fields (like name, gender) using multer in form data. Along with this I am handling file validation errors using fileFilter property.

On hitting request it's only uploading images and not getting data as form data. I am trying to send data as json then data is upload but file upload is not working.
So how to upload file with input files along with custom error handling using multer?